# Is "Modeling Users for Fraud Detection" too generic for a patent?

Tags: general

In reference to the patent: [US20100094767](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100094767)

This is a generic idea that could be easily considered by anyone with a modicum of BI knowledge and AI acumen. Could this patent possibly be granted?

Answer (score 1):

The document you cite is a patent application, not a patent. Applications are frequently rejected. Claims in applications are almost always much broader than what is eventually granted. I will agree that the first claim of the application is almost comically vague and broad. If you go to the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair), select "Publication Number" and enter 20100094767, you can see the entire application history. This application has, after 9 years of prosecution, been allowed, but the claims look nothing like the application's. Unfortunately the PDF of the allowed claims is an image file so I can't easily quote it here, but take my word it is quite long and specific. Click on the "Image File Wrapper" tab and you can find it. Claim 1 is over two and a half pages long. Long complicated claims are actually weak and narrow. In order to infringe on a claim you need to implement each and every aspect of that claim. Skip even one step and you avoid infringement. The other independent claims are similarly long and complicated.

I didn't bother to read the application so I can't comment on the value or novelty of the invention. I encourage you to read the documents found in the image file wrapper. You can see each of the three non-final rejections, the three final rejections, and each version of the updated claims to try to address the rejections.